# how to remove all header() in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i use yii2

I try :
 - remove header with header_remove();
 - use `<?php header('X-Powered-By:'); ?>`
 - use `ini_set` for set `expose_php = Off` ( i have not access to php.ini in host )

how to remove `X-Powered-By` header ?
how to remove other header like OS, Web Server?

Comment: `expose_php "1" php.ini only` http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from here - http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php, this option can be changed only in `php.ini` file, no other way (I'm not talking about the replacement by the caching front-end or as `mod_headers` capability).